# Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions while attempting to activate

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

When trying to scaffold a new controller the data type is not matched, and shows the following message Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions`1[Sprint_1.Data.Sprint1DbContext]' while attempting to activate 'Sprint_1.Data.Sprint1DbContext'

`Startup.cs`

```
public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }


        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            string connectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("Sprint1DbContextConnection");

            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            services.AddDbContext<Sprint1DbContext>(options => options.
            UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString(connectionString)));
            services.AddMvc();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication(); 
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            });
        }
    }
```

`Sprint1DbContext.cs`

```
  public class Sprint1DbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public Sprint1DbContext(DbContextOptions<Sprint1DbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }
        public DbSet<eProject> eProjects { get; set; }
        public DbSet<status> status { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);
            // Customize the ASP.NET Identity model and override the defaults if needed.
            // For example, you can rename the ASP.NET Identity table names and more.
            // Add your customizations after calling base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        }
    }
```

`Program.cs`

```
  public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
            => CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();

        // EF Core uses this method at design time to access the DbContext
        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args)
            => Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(
                    webBuilder => webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>());
    }
```

`eProject.cs`

```
public class eProject
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string title { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
        public string programLanguage { get; set; }
        public status status { get; set; }
        public eProject()
        {

        }
    }
```

I would like to add a controller to my model,

Comment: You are using Entity which has a mapping file that associates the tables in the Database to the c# classes.  The edmx file contains the mappings.  Best way of updating is to add new table to database and then refresh the mapping through Visual Studios menus.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/data-tools/entity-data-model-tools-in-visual-studio?force_isolation=true&view=vs-2022

Comment: Have you read the  official document :https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/    and try:public class Sprint1DbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(_connectionString);
    }